# OpenStreetMap - assembling a hierarchy for Russian Federation

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm currently working with OSM/Nominatim and getting ready to create a hierarchical tree of Russia's administrative districts starting from district, and ending with city. As the PostgreSQL from [Geografik](http://download.geofabrik.de/russia.html) being parsed into the database, and has taken quite a while, I'm wondering if there are any other ways to gather such hierarchy.

One that I found was [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), but its query language is quite cryptic.

The other was [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org) which I'm also not yet 100% how to operate with.

Are there are instruments out there that would allow me to extract specific administrative level(s) (3 to 6) data for Russia quickly?

**Update**

Having read about Nominatim configuration, I'm importing a much lesser dataset for [administrative boundaries and places](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import-and-Update/) through settings/import-admin.style.